# Note from win-builder (Building a R package)

Tags: r

I can not get around this NOTE when I send my package to win-builder.

> Found the following (possibly) invalid file URI:
>     URI: CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
>       From: README.md

https://win-builder.r-project.org/xj4Cz25frL66/00check.log

https://github.com/PMassicotte/eemR

The `CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md` file is in my root directory and, I think, correctly linked in the `README.Rmd` file as follows:

`Please note that the 'eemR' project is released with a [Contributor Code of Conduct](CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md). By contributing to this project, you agree to abide by its terms.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You exclude `CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md` from the built package in your `.Rbuildignore` file. So the `README.md` in the built package can't find the linked file.

Comment: I should have thought of it. Thank you very much.